# Mysql import the most recent file from a directory

Tags: command-line, terminal, pipe, mysql, command

I have a directory with daily backups of my entire MySQL database.
I want to import the most recent backup into the database.

I know to import a backup I need to use `mysql -u root -ppasswordhere < backup.sql`

I've managed to get the most recent file with `ls -Art | grep '.sql' | tail -n 1`, but I don't really know how to pipe the output to the command `mysql -u root -ppasswordhere`

I am sure the answer is really obvious, I'm just confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
mysql -u root -ppasswordhere < $(ls -Art | grep '.sql' | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: you are welcome. if you want to accept the answer then please click on the according `tick` button. like shown here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: I know, I know. I was waiting for the time limit. I cannot accept the answer in the first... (I guess) 15 minutes.